# laravel Pivot table for Many to Many relation without laravel convention

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have 2 model `user` and `team`, every team can have multiple users and each user can be in any team , so I wanna make a many to many relation.

I'm trying to customize something , I don't wanna use the laravel convention for pivot table.

Here is my User Migration:

```
 class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    protected $collection = "table_users";
    public function up()
    {
           Schema::create(  $this->collection
             , function (Blueprint $table) {

                    $table->string('_id');
                    $table->string('username')->unique();
                    $table->string('password');
             }
    }

}
```

And here is my Team Migration :

```
 class CreateTeamTable extends Migration
{
    protected $collection = "table_team";
    public function up()
    {
           Schema::create(  $this->collection
             , function (Blueprint $table) {

                    $table->string('_id');
                    $table->string('name')->unique();
             }
    }

}
```

So my problem is when I want to create method for the relation in `User` Model and `Team` Model.

in Team Model :

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, '??', '??' , '??'); // what should I insert in '??'
    }
```

in User Model :

```
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, '??', '??' , '??'); // what should I insert in '??'
    }
```

And also how to create Pivot table without using any convention:

pivot table that I created so far:

```
class CreateUsersTeamTable extends Migration
{
    protected $collection = "team_user_pivot";
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create(  $this->collection
            , function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('??');  // please help me to fill this field
            $table->string('??');  // please help me to fill this field
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

There are `'??'` in `User` Model and `Team` model and Pivot table . help me to fill up each of them

Comment: You are bucking a lot of conventions here.  If you want to use non-autoincrementing primary key in your tables then you need add public $increments=false; in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as filling in the fields, as you're using a string for the foreign key as well as not follwing the standard namig conventions.

`create_team_user_pivot`

```
protected $collection = "team_user_pivot";

public function up()
{
  Schema::create($this->collection, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('team__id')->references('_id')->on('teams');
    $table->string('user__id')->references('_id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

You also need to edit the models:

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public $table = 'table_users';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        "_id",
        "username",
        "password"
    ];

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_user_pivot', 'user__id', 'team__id');
    }
}
```

**Team**

```
class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'table_teams';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_user_pivot', 'team__id', 'user__id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create another model with migration

```
class UserTeam extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'user_has_team';
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'team_id'];
}
```

in your team model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_has_team', 'user_id', 'team_id');
}
```

in your user model

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'user_has_team', 'team_id', 'user_id');
}
```